# Google Play Games Services View for Popups

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

I just integrated Google Play Game Services for my game. In the log cat I see a warning saying:

```
"10-29 23:13:29.559: W/PopupManager(6985): You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view which may not work properly in future versions of the API. Use setViewForPopups() to set your content view."
```

Is this something I should worry about? Google's default view and layout is okay with me. Also, If I push the home button or go into settings in the Leaderboards activity it shows a force close - is not having a view for popups the cause of that issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["You have not specified a View to use as content for popups"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923638/you-have-not-specified-a-view-to-use-as-content-for-popups)

Comment: Not really a duplicate because his was crashing due to some other error and I don't think he resolved this warning message.

Comment: @Barodapride - did you ever find out what this actually was?  I have this in my LogCat, but everything is working fine.

Comment: I don't think I was able to resolve it. Just living with the warning.

Comment: I remember the same problem and I think it went away with: http://pastebin.com/qTyicmWy.

Answer (score 5):

This should get things working:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the Google API Client with access to Plus, Games and Drive
    // Also set the view for popups
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
            .setViewForPopups(findViewById(android.R.id.content))
            .build();

}
```

**android.R.id.content** gives you the root element of a view, without having to know its actual name/type/ID. Check out Get root view from current activity